# Adding values to a dataframe columnwise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe, `df1`

```
Items_sold        Stock
100                1.11
150                2.22
200                3.33
```

And another `df2`

```
Items_sold_pred    Stock_pred
50                   1.11
100                  2.22
150                  3.33
```

How do I add the last values of the last row of `df1` to `df2` column wise, such that `df2` gets a final output like this? I simply add `100` and `3.33` to `Items_sold_pred` and `Stock_pred` respectively.

```
Items_sold_pred    Stock_pred
250                  4.44
300                  5.55
350                  6.66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iloc[-1]` to get the last row. Since your dataframes have different columns, you want to use `.values` to pass a numpy array:

```
df2.add(df1.iloc[-1].values)
```

Output:

```
   Items_sold  Stock
0       250.0   4.44
1       300.0   5.55
2       350.0   6.66
```

If you want to modify `df2`, you can use `+=` instead:

```
df2 += (df1.iloc[-1].values)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tail too:

```
df2.add(df1.tail(1).values)

   Items_sold_pred  Stock_pred
0            250.0        4.44
1            300.0        5.55
2            350.0        6.66
```